# The arbitrary function that calculates some number$ f(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Theorem 3.8 Let f be an arbitrary function that calculates some number $f(A)$ for any square matrix $A$ of size $N$. Assume that f is multilinear as a function of the rows and that $f(A)$ equal to zero if two rows are zero. Then $f(A)=|A|\cdot f(I)$.

Could someone please tell me the use of these function and tell me something more about this function ? I understand much about determinants, but i can't understand how to use this arbitrary function $f$.

Sincerely
Kim

Comment: The idea here is that there are almost "no" arbitrary functions. Once you define $f(I)$, $f$ is basically just the determinant, up to multiplication with $f(I)$.